# push data from JSON file to a geoJSON array via .each

Tags: jquery, json, each, geojson, mapbox

Okay so i just started working with jQuery and Leaflet, so please bear with me.
I have a big JSON file with 17000 lines of data, wich i want to convert to geoJSON so i can easily implement it in Mapbox. I based it of [this](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/load-geojson/) example of mapbox js website.

This works:

```
var geojson = [];
    geojson.push( 
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [-77.03238901390978,38.913188059745586]
},
"properties": {
  "title": "Mapbox DC",
  "description": "1714 14th St NW, Washington DC",
  "marker-color": "#fc4353",
  "marker-size": "large",
  "marker-symbol": "monument"
}
```

And this doesn't, no errors in console, the markers just disappear:

```
var geojson = [];
$.getJSON('data.json', function(raw){
$.each(raw, function(index, data){
geojson.push( 
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [-77.03238901390978,38.913188059745586]
},
"properties": {
  "title": "Mapbox DC",
  "description": "1714 14th St NW, Washington DC",
  "marker-color": "#fc4353",
  "marker-size": "large",
  "marker-symbol": "monument"
}
}
);
});
});
```

Than i just do as the example states :

```
L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-9ijuk24y').setView([37.8, -96], 4).markerLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);
```

I also do a conole.log(geojson); in both cases and the formatting of both the arrays looks exact the same. one with one entry and one with 1570 entries.

Edit: Here is my console. I unfold the array of 1570 and then I unfold one entry:

[image]

Comment: My guess is you are using that last snippet outside of the complete callback to getJSON, meaning you're using it before data exists.

Comment: my console.log is between the getJSON and the L.mapbox.map and it gives this:
http://imgur.com/zjCdXLA

Comment: Ok at first i didnt get what you were saying. I put the L.mapbox.map in the each loop first, wich was pretty stupid cause it tried to redraw it 1570 times.
Than i put it in the getJSON, but outside the each and it worked!

Thanks, you're smart!